# How do you uninstall an app on Ubuntu Linux that displays in Show Applications, but is not "installed"

Tags: uninstall

Checked `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, the name of the program was not there.
I `grep`ped for it in my systemwide and there is a `.py` file with the name of the app, so `[app].py`.
I had two versions installed and one was uninstalled easily with `apt-get remove`.
The other is not listed in `apt-cache` nor in `snap`.

So, I don't know where these [app] files are, but I would like to remove them.

`whereis [app].py` returns empty.

Thanks for your help.
Mike

Comment: How you safely and effectively uninstall an application depends upon how you originally installed it. There is no single incantation to globally-uninstall an application regardless of forgotten install method.

Comment: So it does not show in `apt list --installed`or in `snap list` but you can run it from the application menu?

Answer (score 0):

An app that appears in "Show Applications" is installed. Application launchers for which the executable is not found, will not appear in "Show Applications". If the launcher does appear, then the executable is still in the expected location in the system.

If that application is not indicated as "installed" through a package manager, then it has not been installed through a package manager. It then must have been installed another way. Only you can know.

You can find the `. desktop` file you want to remove and see which executable it points to on the `Exec=` line. For this, you can use the command `find` as:

find / -name '*.desktop' -exec grep -H "Name=Weather" {} ;

Open the `.desktop` file to see the executable specified. That executable will be on your system, otherwise the launcher would not show up in "Applications" in the first place.